# How to upload multiple files in website, and add it as an attachment to a new record in Odoo 15?

Tags: python, odoo, erp, odoo-15

I'm trying to upload multiple files from the Odoo website, and then call a controller with method post to create a record and save the attachment.

this is my module student.py

```
   ref = fields.Char(string="Ref")
   first_name = fields.Char(string="Firstname")
   last_name = fields.Char(string="Lastname")
   task_attachment = fields.Many2many(comodel_name="ir.attachment",
                        relation="m2m_ir_identity_card_rel",
                        column1="m2m_id",
                        column2="attachment_id",
                        string="Identity Card")
```

And this is my form and input on web_form.xml

```
 <form role="form" action="/create/webstudent" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
   <div class="form-group">
       <label for="student_file" class="control-label">File Of Student :</label>
       <input type="file" name="task_attachment" multiple="true"/>
    </div>

    <div class="clearfix oe_login_buttons">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-left">Submit</button>
    </div>
  </form>
```

And this is my controller

```
@http.route('/create/webstudent', type="http", auth="user", website=True)
  def create_webpatient(self, **kw):
   if request.httprequest.method == 'POST':
    new_task = request.env['university.student'].sudo().create(kw)
    if 'task_attachment' in request.params:
        attached_files = request.httprequest.files.getlist('task_attachment')
        for attachment in attached_files:
            attached_file = attachment.read()
            request.env['ir.attachment'].sudo().create({
                'name': attachment.filename,
                'res_model': 'university.student',
                'res_id': new_task.id,
                'type': 'binary',
                'datas_fname': attachment.filename,
                'datas': attached_file.encode('base64'),
            })

   return request.render("om_university.student_thanks", {})
```

When I click the submit button this error shows up :

```
    500: Internal Server Error
      Traceback
    Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "C:\Users\nacer\Desktop\learning_odoo\odooWorkspace\odoo- 
   15\odoo\odoo\addons\base\models\ir_http.py", line 237, in _dispatch
    result = request.dispatch()
  File "C:\Users\nacer\Desktop\learning_odoo\odooWorkspace\odoo- 
  15\odoo\odoo\http.py", line 811, in dispatch
    r = self._call_function(**self.params)
  File "C:\Users\nacer\Desktop\learning_odoo\odooWorkspace\odoo- 
  15\odoo\odoo\http.py", line 360, in _call_function
    return checked_call(self.db, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\nacer\Desktop\learning_odoo\odooWorkspace\odoo- 
  15\odoo\odoo\service\model.py", line 94, in wrapper
    return f(dbname, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\nacer\Desktop\learning_odoo\odooWorkspace\odoo- 
  15\odoo\odoo\http.py", line 349, in checked_call
    result = self.endpoint(*a, **kw)
  File "C:\Users\nacer\Desktop\learning_odoo\odooWorkspace\odoo- 
  15\odoo\odoo\http.py", line 917, in __call__
    return self.method(*args, **kw)
  File "C:\Users\nacer\Desktop\learning_odoo\odooWorkspace\odoo- 
  15\odoo\odoo\http.py", line 536, in response_wrap
    response = f(*args, **kw)
  File "c:\users\nacer\desktop\learning_odoo\odooworkspace\odoo- 
  15\custom_addons\om_university\controllers\controllers.py", line 29, 
  in create_webpatient
    new_task = request.env['university.student'].sudo().create(kw)
  File "<decorator-gen-131>", line 2, in create
  File "C:\Users\nacer\Desktop\learning_odoo\odooWorkspace\odoo- 
  15\odoo\odoo\api.py", line 412, in _model_create_multi
    return create(self, [arg])
  File "C:\Users\nacer\Desktop\learning_odoo\odooWorkspace\odoo- 
  15\odoo\addons\mail\models\mail_thread.py", line 265, in create
    threads = super(MailThread, self).create(vals_list)
  File "<decorator-gen-67>", line 2, in create
  File "C:\Users\nacer\Desktop\learning_odoo\odooWorkspace\odoo- 
  15\odoo\odoo\api.py", line 413, in _model_create_multi
    return create(self, arg)
  File "C:\Users\nacer\Desktop\learning_odoo\odooWorkspace\odoo- 
  15\odoo\odoo\addons\base\models\ir_fields.py", line 613, in create
    recs = super().create(vals_list)
  File "<decorator-gen-13>", line 2, in create
  File "C:\Users\nacer\Desktop\learning_odoo\odooWorkspace\odoo- 
  15\odoo\odoo\api.py", line 413, in _model_create_multi
    return create(self, arg)
  File "C:\Users\nacer\Desktop\learning_odoo\odooWorkspace\odoo- 
  15\odoo\odoo\models.py", line 4070, in create
    records = self._create(data_list)
  File "C:\Users\nacer\Desktop\learning_odoo\odooWorkspace\odoo- 
  15\odoo\odoo\models.py", line 4220, in _create
    field.create([
  File "C:\Users\nacer\Desktop\learning_odoo\odooWorkspace\odoo- 
  15\odoo\odoo\fields.py", line 3283, in create
    self.write_batch(record_values, True)
  File "C:\Users\nacer\Desktop\learning_odoo\odooWorkspace\odoo- 
  15\odoo\odoo\fields.py", line 3304, in write_batch
    raise ValueError("Wrong value for %s: %s" % (self, value))
   Exception
  The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
   Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\nacer\Desktop\learning_odoo\odooWorkspace\odoo- 
  15\odoo\odoo\addons\base\models\ir_http.py", line 237, in _dispatch
    result = request.dispatch()
  File "C:\Users\nacer\Desktop\learning_odoo\odooWorkspace\odoo- 
  15\odoo\odoo\http.py", line 811, in dispatch
    r = self._call_function(**self.params)
  File "C:\Users\nacer\Desktop\learning_odoo\odooWorkspace\odoo- 
  15\odoo\odoo\http.py", line 360, in _call_function
    return checked_call(self.db, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\nacer\Desktop\learning_odoo\odooWorkspace\odoo- 
  15\odoo\odoo\service\model.py", line 94, in wrapper
    return f(dbname, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\nacer\Desktop\learning_odoo\odooWorkspace\odoo- 
  15\odoo\odoo\http.py", line 349, in checked_call
    result = self.endpoint(*a, **kw)
  File "C:\Users\nacer\Desktop\learning_odoo\odooWorkspace\odoo- 
  15\odoo\odoo\http.py", line 917, in __call__
    return self.method(*args, **kw)
  File "C:\Users\nacer\Desktop\learning_odoo\odooWorkspace\odoo- 
  15\odoo\odoo\http.py", line 536, in response_wrap
    response = f(*args, **kw)
  File "c:\users\nacer\desktop\learning_odoo\odooworkspace\odoo- 
  15\custom_addons\om_university\controllers\controllers.py", line 29, 
   in create_webpatient
    new_task = request.env['university.student'].sudo().create(kw)
  File "<decorator-gen-131>", line 2, in create
  File "C:\Users\nacer\Desktop\learning_odoo\odooWorkspace\odoo- 
  15\odoo\odoo\api.py", line 412, in _model_create_multi
    return create(self, [arg])
  File "C:\Users\nacer\Desktop\learning_odoo\odooWorkspace\odoo- 
  15\odoo\addons\mail\models\mail_thread.py", line 265, in create
    threads = super(MailThread, self).create(vals_list)
  File "<decorator-gen-67>", line 2, in create
  File "C:\Users\nacer\Desktop\learning_odoo\odooWorkspace\odoo- 
   15\odoo\odoo\api.py", line 413, in _model_create_multi
    return create(self, arg)
  File "C:\Users\nacer\Desktop\learning_odoo\odooWorkspace\odoo- 
  15\odoo\odoo\addons\base\models\ir_fields.py", line 613, in create
    recs = super().create(vals_list)
  File "<decorator-gen-13>", line 2, in create
  File "C:\Users\nacer\Desktop\learning_odoo\odooWorkspace\odoo- 
  15\odoo\odoo\api.py", line 413, in _model_create_multi
    return create(self, arg)
  File "C:\Users\nacer\Desktop\learning_odoo\odooWorkspace\odoo- 
  15\odoo\odoo\models.py", line 4070, in create
    records = self._create(data_list)
  File "C:\Users\nacer\Desktop\learning_odoo\odooWorkspace\odoo- 
  15\odoo\odoo\models.py", line 4220, in _create
    field.create([
  File "C:\Users\nacer\Desktop\learning_odoo\odooWorkspace\odoo- 
  15\odoo\odoo\fields.py", line 3283, in create
    self.write_batch(record_values, True)
  File "C:\Users\nacer\Desktop\learning_odoo\odooWorkspace\odoo- 
  15\odoo\odoo\fields.py", line 3304, in write_batch
    raise ValueError("Wrong value for %s: %s" % (self, value))
  ValueError: Wrong value for university.student.image_1920: 
   <FileStorage: '888j06068.jpg' ('image/jpeg')>
```

can anybody help me, please!

Comment: Could you please click on the [Show Error Details] to provide us the entire Error TraceBack ?

Comment: Okay, I did that.

Comment: let's have a look in in /web_editor/main.py : def _attachment_create... and my edited post below...

Comment: I want to add multiple files with multiple type, like (pdf, png, and jpg..), not just (image) Sorry I'm new in Odoo can you explain your answer, why you put two functions in the controller.

Comment: my post contains only the original code of odoo core... just to take it as example

Answer (score 1):

1st EXAMPLE : multiple files uploads

web/static/src/xml/base.xml

```xml
<t t-name="web.CustomFileInput" owl="1">
    <span class="o_file_input" aria-atomic="true">
        <span class="o_file_input_trigger" t-on-click.prevent="_onTriggerClicked">
            <t t-slot="default">
                <button class="btn btn-primary">Choose File</button>
            </t>
        </span>
        <input type="file" name="ufile" class="o_input_file d-none"
            t-att="{multiple: props.multi_upload, accept: props.accepted_file_extensions}"
            t-ref="file-input"
            t-on-change="_onFileInputChange"
        />
    </span>
</t>
```

```js
async _uploadFiles(files, params={}) {
        if (!files || !files.length) { return; }

        await new Promise(resolve => {
            const xhr = this._createXhr();
            xhr.open('POST', this._getFileUploadRoute());
      //...
      //...
_getFileUploadRoute() {
        return '/documents/upload_attachment';
    },
```

controllers/main.py

```py
@http.route('/documents/upload_attachment', type='http', methods=['POST'], auth="user")
    def upload_document(self, folder_id, ufile, document_id=False, partner_id=False, owner_id=False):
        files = request.httprequest.files.getlist('ufile')
        result = {'success': _("All files uploaded")}
        tag_ids = request.params.pop('tag_ids', None)
        tag_ids = tag_ids.split(',') if tag_ids else []
        if document_id:
            document = request.env['documents.document'].browse(int(document_id))
            ufile = files[0]
            try:
                data = base64.encodebytes(ufile.read())
                mimetype = ufile.content_type
                document.write({
                    'name': ufile.filename,
                    'datas': data,
                    'mimetype': mimetype,
                })
            except Exception as e:
                logger.exception("Fail to upload document %s" % ufile.filename)
                result = {'error': str(e)}
        else:
            vals_list = []
            for ufile in files:
                try:
                    mimetype = ufile.content_type
                    datas = base64.encodebytes(ufile.read())
                    vals = {
                        'name': ufile.filename,
                        'mimetype': mimetype,
                        'datas': datas,
                        'folder_id': int(folder_id),
                        'tag_ids': tag_ids,
                        'partner_id': int(partner_id)
                    }
                    if owner_id:
                        vals['owner_id'] = int(owner_id)
                    vals_list.append(vals)
                except Exception as e:
                    logger.exception("Fail to upload document %s" % ufile.filename)
                    result = {'error': str(e)}
            documents = request.env['documents.document'].create(vals_list)
            result['ids'] = documents.ids

        return json.dumps(result)
```

models/document.py

```py
class Document(models.Model):
    _name = 'documents.document'
    @api.model
    def create(self, vals):
        keys = [key for key in vals if
                self._fields[key].related and self._fields[key].related[0] == 'attachment_id']
        attachment_dict = {key: vals.pop(key) for key in keys if key in vals}
        attachment = self.env['ir.attachment'].browse(vals.get('attachment_id'))

        if attachment and attachment_dict:
            attachment.write(attachment_dict)
        elif attachment_dict:
            attachment_dict.setdefault('name', vals.get('name', 'unnamed'))
            attachment = self.env['ir.attachment'].create(attachment_dict)
            vals['attachment_id'] = attachment.id
        new_record = super(Document, self).create(vals)

        # this condition takes precedence during forward-port.
        if (attachment and not attachment.res_id and (not attachment.res_model or attachment.res_model == 'documents.document')):
            attachment.with_context(no_document=True).write({'res_model': 'documents.document', 'res_id': new_record.id})
        return new_record
```

2nd EXAMPLE: in web_editor/static/src/xml/wysiwyg.xml

```xml
<input type="file" class="d-none o_file_input" name="upload" t-att-accept="widget.options.accept" t-att-multiple="widget.options.multiImages &amp;&amp; 'multiple'"/>
```

in web_editor/static/src/js/wysiwyg/widgets/media.js

```js
/**
 * Let users choose a file, including uploading a new file in odoo.
 */
var FileWidget = SearchableMediaWidget.extend({
    events: _.extend({}, SearchableMediaWidget.prototype.events || {}, {
        'click .o_upload_media_button': '_onUploadButtonClick',
        'change .o_file_input': '_onFileInputChange',
/**
     * Handles change of the file input: create attachments with the new files
     * and open the Preview dialog for each of them. Locks the save button until
     * all new files have been processed.
     *
     * @private
     * @returns {Promise}
     */
    _onFileInputChange: function () {
        return this._mutex.exec(this._addData.bind(this));
    },
/**
     * Uploads the files that are currently selected on the file input, which
     * creates new attachments. Then inserts them on the media dialog and
     * selects them. If multiImages is not set, also triggers up the
     * save_request event to insert the attachment in the DOM.
     *
     * @private
     * @returns {Promise}
     */
    async _addData() {
        let files = this.$fileInput[0].files;
        if (!files.length) {
            // Case if the input is emptied, return resolved promise
            return;
        }

        var self = this;
        var uploadMutex = new concurrency.Mutex();

        // Upload the smallest file first to block the user the least possible.
        files = _.sortBy(files, 'size');
        _.each(files, function (file) {
            // Upload one file at a time: no need to parallel as upload is
            // limited by bandwidth.
            uploadMutex.exec(function () {
                return utils.getDataURLFromFile(file).then(function (result) {
                    return self._rpc({
                        route: '/web_editor/attachment/add_data',
                        params: {
                            'name': file.name,
                            'data': result.split(',')[1],
                            'res_id': self.options.res_id,
                            'res_model': self.options.res_model,
                            'width': 0,
                            'quality': 0,
                        },
                    }).then(function (attachment) {
                        self._handleNewAttachment(attachment);
                    });
                });
            });
        });
```

in /web_editor/main.py

```py
    @http.route('/web_editor/attachment/add_data', type='json', auth='user', methods=['POST'], website=True)
    def add_data(self, name, data, quality=0, width=0, height=0, res_id=False, res_model='ir.ui.view', **kwargs):
        try:
            data = tools.image_process(data, size=(width, height), quality=quality, verify_resolution=True)
        except UserError:
            pass  # not an image
        self._clean_context()
        attachment = self._attachment_create(name=name, data=data, res_id=res_id, res_model=res_model)
        return attachment._get_media_info()


    def _attachment_create(self, name='', data=False, url=False, res_id=False, res_model='ir.ui.view'):
        """Create and return a new attachment."""
        if name.lower().endswith('.bmp'):
            # Avoid mismatch between content type and mimetype, see commit msg
            name = name[:-4]

        if not name and url:
            name = url.split("/").pop()

        if res_model != 'ir.ui.view' and res_id:
            res_id = int(res_id)
        else:
            res_id = False

        attachment_data = {
            'name': name,
            'public': res_model == 'ir.ui.view',
            'res_id': res_id,
            'res_model': res_model,
        }

        if data:
            attachment_data['datas'] = data
        elif url:
            attachment_data.update({
                'type': 'url',
                'url': url,
            })
        else:
            raise UserError(_("You need to specify either data or url to create an attachment."))

        attachment = request.env['ir.attachment'].create(attachment_data)
        return attachment
```